# index out of range on board game last square

Tags: c#

I am creating a board game for an assignment and I am almost complete, however the player tokens keep going past the last square and causing an error.  Here is the method I am calling to move the tokens on the board:

```
private void Move(int numberOfSquares) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSquares; i++) {
                if (Location.NextSquare == null) {

                    location = this.Location;
                } else {
                    location = location.NextSquare;
                }
            }
```

In the first if statement I want the token location to remain unchanged if the nextsquare value is beyond the final square.  Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the code to:

```
private void Move(int numberOfSquares) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSquares; i++) {
        if (location.NextSquare == null) {
            break;
        } else {
            location = location.NextSquare;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Andrew  I tried your code and it improves it but it has not eliminated the problem for some reason.  I am still getting outofbounds error every 1 to 2 games I play.

Comment: What is location initialized to?  And also, what is the number of squares initialized to?  Can the number of squares decrease during the game?  Are there other places where you update the location?

Comment: Location of tokens is initialised to square 0 at the start.  There is a maximum of 42 squares with the last square representing the finish of the array.  The number of squares is fixed.  The location is only changed by the NextSquare method.

Comment: public Square NextSquare {
              get {
                    Debug.Assert (Number <     Board.FINISH_SQUARE_NUMBER, "Number <     Board.FINISH_SQUARE_NUMBER", 
                        "The Finish square is the last     square.");
                    return Board.Squares[Number + 1];
                }
            }

Comment: Could you paste the class definition of Location, and the code you used to initialize this.location

Comment: oh I see, it's not a linked list, then you need to say: if Number == Finish_SQAURE_NUMBER, return null. since the last square does not have a next.

Comment: // current square that player is on
        private Square  location; 
        public Square  Location {
            get {
                return location;
            }
            set {
                location = value;

            }
        }

Comment: Ok so Im turning the NextSquare method into an If statement?